# How can I stream Counter-Strike 1.6 on Twitch using OBS?

Tags: counter-strike, streaming, twitch

I am very new to streaming, only tried and managed to hook up a stream for Heroes of the Storm, so I have no idea how I can do this.

Using NVIDIA GeForce Control Panel, I specified NVIDIA as the graphics card when running cstrike.exe and started the game in windowed mode, however, OBS doesn't seem to capture anything.

[image]

How can I make this work?

Comment: Care to explain downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a decent enough Nvidia card, you should be able to use [ShadowPlay](http://www.geforce.com/geforce-experience/shadowplay) through GeForce Experience, set to the Twitch mode.  I've used it for quite a while now, and it has unparalleled quality, and doesn't really ruin your FPS.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got to make ShadowPlay work on my laptops GTX 750M and managed to broadcast Warcraft III, however I'm having issues with OpenGL games like this CS 1.6. Another workaround suggested is to use desktop capture mode, but unfortunately, that is not an option for the laptop drivers. Any thoughts on the subject of how can I broadcast OpenGL games on my laptop?

Comment: Well, I can desktop capture from OBS, which sort of solves my problem. Thanks for the shadow play suggestion, I learned a few new stuff :)